# Cannot get value of hyperlink set by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have got a form view with a image field with hyperlink. The image and hyperlink are set by jquery autocomplete. I can succesfully see the image on screen, and I can succesfully click on the image for the hyperlink. But when I want to insert the image url to the database, it is empty. The same code for text boxes work fine. How can I insert the image url into the database?

The form view with the hyperlink (id=lnkZoomImg)

```
<asp:FormView
ID="FormView1"
runat="server"
DataKeyNames="kado_id"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
DefaultMode="Insert"
OnItemInserting="cadeau_inserting"
OnItemInserted="cadeau_inserted"
CssClass="formview">

<InsertItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="lblImg" text="" CssClass="size_l" AssociatedControlID="lnkZoomImg" runat="server" />
    <asp:hyperlink id="lnkZoomImg" CssClass="popup-link" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("img_url") %>' runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Image ID="imgArtikel" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("img_url") %>' CssClass="imgcadeau" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </asp:hyperlink>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" CommandName="Insert" Text="<i class='fa fa-check'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Voeg toe" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="drukknop" runat="server" /><br />

</InsertItemTemplate>
```

The hyperlink is populated by jQuery. This works fine.

```
function updateTextBox(event, ui) {
    $('#lnkZoomImg').attr('href', ui.item.imgURL);
    return false;
}
```

Finally I want to add the data to the database. This is done by clicking on btnInsert inside the FormView. Before the insert takes place, cadeau_inserting is executed. The problem is that CType(FormView1.FindControl("lnkZoomImg"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl is empty. Among this hyperlink also text boxes are used in exactly the same way, and that works fine.

```
Sub cadeau_inserting(ByVal Src As Object, ByVal Args As FormViewInsertEventArgs)

    Args.Values("img_url") = CType(FormView1.FindControl("lnkZoomImg"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Not showing where you call this function. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: When clicking the insert-button of the formview, the sub cadeau_inserting is executed. The problem is that CType(FormView1.FindControl("lnkZoomImg"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl is an empty string

Comment: Don't post a bunch of non relevant code. That just makes it more confusing and hard to inspect. Please thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: I think I posted the relevant code, with explaination of its purpose

Comment: I hope someone can help me out?